# JPanel check if values changed

Tags: java, swing, oop, jpanel

Lets say I have 2 JPanels.
I create both of them while program is loading and set 2nd to visible(false). 2nd JPanel uses information entered in 1st JPanel. I want to use that information.
However since both panels are created at the same time the value from 1st Panel will be null.

I need something like repaint(), but it should repaint all JTextFields with new variable values. I can't find anything useful in java api.

Is there something like this in java?
If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in the second JPanel that sets all the values up.

Pass a reference to the second JPanel into the first.

When the first is ready it can call the method in the second to set all the values.